# Is the set open? Closed?

Tags: real-analysis

I am given two sets:

$$A=\Big\{(-1)^n + \frac{2}{n}: n=1,2,3,...\Big\}$$

and

$$B=\{x \in \mathbb{Q}\ |\ 0<x<1\}$$

I am asked to determine if each set is open or closed. I have found an answer below. However, I am having trouble comprehending why this answer is true.  [image: here]

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Can you pinpoint more exactly what about that answer you do not understand? For example, do you understand what rational numbers and irrational numbers are? Do you understand what an open interval is? And so on. Without knowing exactly what you know, we might have to write a whole chapter to explain this answer.

Comment: I understand what rational numbers and irrational numbers are and I understand the theorem for Density of $\mathbb{Q}$...i could use some more clarification on the definition of an open set...is a set open if it contains its limit points?

Comment: @rover2: A set is closed (not **open**) if it contains all its [limit points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point).

Comment: $A$ has points arbitrarily near $-1$ but it does not contain $-1$. Similarly, $B$ has points arbitrarily near $0$ but it does not contain $0$. So neither set is closed. Neither set contains any open interval at all (let alone an open interval around each of its points), so neither set is open.

Comment: can you explain or show why neither set contains any open interval? @Bungo

Comment: Every open interval contains irrational numbers, but both $A$ and $B$ contain only rational numbers.

Comment: Do you mean open/closed in $\mathbb R$?